# How jsp can access getters and setters in superclass, Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Using spring MVC
I have some class with property, and getter\setter to get access to this property

```
class a{
private String something;
public void setSomething(String something){
    this.something = something;}
public String getSomething(){
return something;
}
```

And I have subclass with some new property, getter and setter in it

```
class b extends a{
private String newProp;
public void setNewProp(String newProp){
    this.newProp = newProp;}
public String getNewProp(){
return newProp;
}
```

When I trying to get property value in jsp, that defined in superclass like this

```
${b-inst.something}
```

I've got "is not readable or had invalid getter" error
Is it possible to get access to that superclass property without changing this property to protected, and writing it's getter\setter in subclass(because I'm losing inheritance benefits in that way)?

Comment: Post your REAL code, and the complete error message. And please, format it properly.

Comment: @JBNizet "post your REAL code" is quite the bad advice. This is Stack Overflow, MCVE is what is correct here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correct case for the property: `userName` instead of `username` (just like your `firstName` and `lastName` properties)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, it helped. I thought it's some inheritance problem, but it's attention deficiency problem

Comment: I think you should accept the answer then (and remember it is always appreciated to accept working answers ;)

Comment: I can understand how you guessed this?

Comment: Telepathy 80 lvl :) Actually there was an answer by OP with code example and clarifications which he deleted after accepting the write answer. I suppose he did it this way because of too low reputation for adding comments or editing the question.